# Ubuntu 18.04.3 doesn't boot after expanding disk space in Hyper-V

Tags: boot, 18.04, partitioning, swap, hyper-v

I ran into a problem with my disk space after I increased my swap size. I had 30GB disk space allocated to Ubuntu and I increased my swap size to 8GB which depleted all remaining disk space. After that I tried to increase my disk space from 30 to 50GB. I've done this before from 10GB to 20GB and then 20GB to 30GB and I didn't have an issue. Now when I've done it from 50 I get this error on boot from Ubuntu:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWjsh.png)

I since then went back to 30GB but still the same error.

After that is finished I get prompted the Xorg login and when I try to log in it waits for a long time and gives me this error.

[Xorg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9ToS.png)

I'm not sure what can be done here.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the services as suggested by the error messages in your posted image. systemctl status ..........  You might need to ask a new question based on what that shows.

Comment: @PonJar how do I access these files?

Comment: Open a terminal and type the command. systemctl status ......  Replace ........... with the particular text suggested in your image. There are several different services with errors so you will need to do this a few times to get the full picture. When you have typed the command you will get some output which will probably describe the problem. It’s probably one problem kicking off a series of errors. You will need to press “Q” or “q” to exit the status report and get back to the command prompt.

Comment: Problem is I can't get into Ubuntu at all. That error screen persists a few times before I get to my Xorg log in prompt then the screen gets stuck on the background image of the login. I tried to boot in safe mode but I can't get past these errors.

Comment: When the screen is “stuck” you should be able to get a command prompt by holding down ctl and alt and then pressing f3. I think you have to log in but then you will be able to use the commands

Comment: @PonJar I've tried to do that but I couldn't as I can't log in. I've edited my post so you can see the new picture and what I wrote about it.

Comment: I’m not familiar with hyper-v and since it is Windows software you might find help on a Windows forum.